# Regular expression to match and extract two version number patterns

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to write a regular expression that will match the version number from a configuration file. I am trying to match and extract the version number from the two following numbering patterns

```
1) <version>2.343</version>
2) <version>2.343.2</version>
```

Such that a result is returned of either

```
1) 2.343
2) 2.343.2
```

My current solution- looks like either one of these two awk commands with the regex pattern to match both cases individually. But there must be a solution that covers both cases?

```
awk 'match($0, /[0-9][.][0-9][0-9][0-9]/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' config.xml
awk 'match($0, /[0-9][.][0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9]/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' config.xml
```

Comment: The unique regexp you are looking for is probably something like `/[0-9]\.[0-9]{3}(\.[0-9])?/` but this is not sufficient because you probably also need to anchor it between `<version>` and `</version>`. Else it will also match in `23.456.78` and `<foo>1.234.5<bar>`.

Comment: Why not just print the value of the `version` tag using a tool that understand your input format, e.g. xlmstarlet if your file is XML?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following. Using `match` function of `awk` here, should work in any POSIX `awk` version. Using regex `>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*<` to match values from `>` followed by version followed by `>` and if regex match is found then printing sub string of matched values.

```bash
awk 'match($0,/>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*</){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' Input_file
```

***OR*** In case you want to exactly looking for version tag then try following:

```bash
awk 'match($0,/<version>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*<\/version>/){print substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-19)}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With your shown samples. Using GNU `awk`'s `RS` variable with same concept of using regex in it and getting values.

```bash
awk -v RS='<version>[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)*<\\/version>' 'RT{split(RT,arr,"[><]");print arr[3]}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 yes that worked. and finding the version tag is also important if for some reason the numbering format is found elsewhere in the file.

Answer (score 5):

You may use:

```bash
awk 'match($0, /[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+/) {
   print $0, substr($2, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' file

1) 2.343
2) 2.343.2
```

Comment: If I correctly understand the OP `/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){1,2}/` would maybe be more accurate.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: For the given examples yes that would be suffice.

Comment: And note that this will match even if not in a `<version>...</version>` structure.

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU awk and the third argument of `match()`:

```
$ gawk 'match($0,/<version>(.*)<\/version>/,a){print a[1]}' file
2.343
2.343.2
```

Comment: Replace maybe `(.*)` by `([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){1,2})`?

Answer (score 4):

Here is another `awk` solution (tested with GNU and BSD `awk`) that tries to match **exactly** the two numbering patterns shown in the OP (`<version>N.NNN</version>` and `<version>N.NNN.N</version>` where `N` is any digit). It assumes that `<version>...</version>` tags are properly balanced, do not appear in comments, strings... and do not span over multiple lines. If several version numbers appear on the same line they are all printed.

```
awk -F '</?version>' '{
  for(i=1; i<=NF/2; i++)
    if($(2*i) ~ /^[0-9]\.[0-9]{3}(\.[0-9])?$/) print $(2*i)
}' config.xml
```

If the components of version numbers can have any number of digits (minimum 1) just relax the regular expression: `/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){1,2}$/`. And if there can be any number of components (minimum 1) relax a bit more: `/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$/` (or `/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+$/` for at least 2 components).

If `<version>...</version>` tags are not properly balanced, can appear in comments, or can span over several lines, a real XML parser would be a much better solution than a general purpose utility like `awk`.

Answer (score 3):

absolutely no need to invoke `match()` or resort to vendor-proprietary solutions

> ```
> nawk ++NF OFS='' FS='(^[^>]*)?[<][/]?version[>]($)?'
> ```

```
2.343
2.343.2
```

the brute-force approaches :

> ```
> gawk NF=NF OFS= FS='^[^>]+>|<[/].+$'  # kinda brute-force
>
> mawk NF++ OFS= FS='^[^>]+.|./.+$'     # REALLY brute-force
> ```

```
2.343
2.343.2
```

Comment: You might shorten the first pattern as `FS='(^[^<]*)?</?version>'` But what is the use of `++NF` and `NF++` and `NF=NF` ? And does that have the same effect in different awk versions?

Comment: @Thefourthbird : ah you're right. Those 3 are identical in this scenario I was simply showcasing multiple equally-valid approaches for the same task.

Answer (score 3):

Your two commands might be melded into one using `?` meaning zero-or-one repetitions as follows

```
awk 'match($0, /[0-9][.][0-9][0-9][0-9](.[0-9])?/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' config.xml
```

which for `config.xml` content as follows

```
1) <version>2.343</version>
2) <version>2.343.2</version>
```

gives output

```
2.343
2.343.2
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*